# breaking up conditional expression

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I'm trying to evaluate if there's a performance hit in writing this expression

```
bool func() {
    if (expr1 || expr2 ... || exprN)
       return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

as

```
bool func() {

    if (expr1)
        return 1;

    if (expr2)
        return 1;

    ...

    if (exprN)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

The reason I'm trying to do the latter is simply to improve readability/maintainability (eg. latter can be written in terms of a helper macro and thereby making it easier to add/remove `expr`s. There are about 50 expressions in this case).

A similar scenario is writing

```
bool func() {
    if (expr1 && expr2 && ... && exprN) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

as

```
bool func() {
    if (!expr1) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (!expr2) {
        return 0;
    }

    ...

    if (!exprN) {
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Is there a performance hit in this case and if so do compilers optimize try to optimize it? I'd be interested to know if `gcc` does that.

(To give some context the expressions themselves are functions and let's say we want to determine if all or at least one returns true. The functions take arguments of different types)

Comment: Print the assembly language listing generated by the compiler.  There should be no difference between the code generated by your examples.

Comment: You should put all `expr1 || expr2` ... etc. into another function.

Comment: More to read does not equal better readability. And your first two code-blocks don't look equivalent.

Comment: Then it's `if (something_true()) do_something();`.

Comment: The list of `if` statements is not equivalent to the single `if` statement in either of your examples. Proving once again the adage that [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Comment: the generated code will be pretty much the same thing... and yes, go to macros soon

Comment: @Deduplicator realised haven't translated the actual code to pseudo code here. Will edit

Comment: @user3386109 not trying to optimize anything here.. just trying to improve readability a bit. Was curious of the performance impact if any

Comment: Your second example will not give you the same results when expanded as the original single-line condition.  All `AND`s need to be true to run do_something() and return 1 in that case, while in the first example, only one `OR` needs to be true.

Comment: @ubi Hmm, "... evaluate if there's a performance hit ...". *Readability* and *performance* are secondary concerns compared to *functionally correct*. But you've corrected the question, so let's move on. The fact that you feel like you need 50 expressions in an `if` statement is the fundamental problem here. That is a very good indication that you have one or more design flaws in the system.  As an example, let's say that I want to verify that a number is between 1 and 50, so I write `if (x==1 || x==2 || ... || x==50)`. That's clearly and obviously the wrong way to solve the problem.

Comment: The point is that I don't think the question here should be about readability *or* tiny performance differences.  The real question here is why the heck do you have 50 expressions in a single `if` statement.

Comment: @user3386109 obviously programming tasks are not always comparing integers... to give some context the expressions are functions and let's say we want to determine if all or at least one returns true. The functions take arguments of different types.

Comment: Yes, you've got the beginnings of a good question in that comment. However, you need to make it concrete. If you continue to insist on keeping the question abstract, you will not find enlightenment. The answers can only be as good as the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your two versions are functionally equivalent.

In C/C++ (and many other languages) the logical operators `||` and `&&` perform ["short-circuit" evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). They evaluate the sub-expressions from left to right, stopping as soon as the result is known. In the case of `||`, this means it stops as soon as it gets a true (non-zero) result (because `true || anything` is true); in the case of `&&`, it stops as soon as it gets a false (zero) result (because `false && anything` is false).

If you were performing any other actions in your `if` bodies other than just returning from the function, it would be duplicated for every expression that's true. But since you're returning from the function as soon as one of the expressions is true, you'll never test any of the remaining expressions. So it's doing the same short-circuiting.

If you did have some action in the body, you could get the same type of short-circuiting by using `else if` rather than `if`. However, this would violate the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle. But if it's in the output of a macro, rather than the original source code, this wouldn't be a signficant concern (although it would likely increase the size of the generated code -- if taken to extremes this could have memory performance implications).

Answer (score 1):

Your current code

```
bool func() {
    if (expr1 || expr2 ... || exprN)
       return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

involving umpteen logical expressions, can be written as the possibly more clear & maintainable

```
auto func()
    -> bool
{
    return false
        || expr1
        || expr2 ...
        || exprN;
}
```

This allows the compiler the best opportunity to optimize, because it's presented with complete information about the desired effect.

In contrast, a series of individual `if` statements would have to be analyzed by the compiler to determine that they implement an OR-chain.

As always when in doubt about micro-performance, **MEASURE**.

Answer (score 0):

The C and C++ codes are generated to its assembly equivalent.
Hence, what i think is that the code generated should not be different unless you have multiple output function or jump statements(including Return, like you have in your second example).
So i think there should be no performance hit unless you have too many jumps in your improved readability code.